# Spring boot running tomcat based on proper profile setting

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to have two profiles in my app `Standalone` without tomcat started and without loading `Controller` settings and `REST` just the opposite. I would like to be able to switch between those options based on profile (if it is possible).

I tried to have two main apps:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "io.dabow")
@EnableJpaRepositories("io.dabow.db.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.dabow.db.entity")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@Profile("REST")
public class ScannerApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       SpringApplication.run(ScannerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and the second one

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "io.dabow")
@EnableJpaRepositories("io.dabow.db.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.dabow.db.entity")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@Profile("Standalone")
public class ScannerApplicationStandalone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ScannerApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
    }
}
```

When I start app with active profile `REST` everything works great, but when I use `REST` profile `ScannerApplication.main` is still fired which I realize is expected behavior.

Could anyone give me a hint on how to make it work properly?

Comment: you could start your application with VM Options: `-Dspring.main.web-application-type=NONE `

Comment: @DirkDeyneI thought about it but I would like to run some service after app start in model without rest api

Comment: you should be able to do that... What is the problem?

Comment: is this [DemoApplication](https://gist.github.com/dirkdeyne/67c6f2ac17cede179cef1f383c288a24) useful?

Comment: Yea this example is exacly what i was looking for! please write an anwser so I can mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a profile to run your application with `WebApplicationType.NONE`.

Just launch your application with the VM Options: `-Dspring.main.web-application-type=NONE`

You can use `@ConditionalOnNotWebApplication` on components, services, ... if you want to do something when your application is launched as *none-web*

Example:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Service
@ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
class DemoService {

    /* triggered if application is started with -Dspring.main.web-application-type=NONE */
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void doStuffIfNoWeb(){
        System.out.println("Hi no web stuff");
    }

}

@RestController
class DemoController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```